# Get element by name using knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am creating input elements like below:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: attr: { name: Data[' + $index() + ']'}" />
```

I have another button which creates multiple inputs of above with its click.

And I also have my main button click as:

```
 <input type="button" value="Check Data" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind='click: verify.bind($data, event)' />
```

In my knockout I have:

```
self.verify= function (data, event) {
  //here I want the data that is entered in each of the inputs.      
}
```

On the above button click I want to get the value of all the inputs. In JS I could have done elements by name and it would give me that element. But how can I get that to work here.

Updated code:

I have this in my HTML:

```
    <div data-bind="foreach: { data: myData }">
        <div class="form">
            <div class="myClass">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: $data.textbox, attr: { name: 'MyData[' + $index() + '].Textbox'}" />
            </div>    
            <div class="myClass">                    
                <input type="button" value="Add More" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: $parent.add"/>
            </div>              
        </div>
    </div>
```

When the user clicks Add More, it adds on more it adds one more text box.
Then at last I have a button as:

```
<div class="form">      
    <input type="button" value="Check Data" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind='click: checkData' />     
</div>
```

When the user clicks on Check Data button I just need to some validation on the all the data entered in the textbox. The validation needs to be done on client side.

In my knockout I have:

```
 this.add = ko.observableArray();

 this.add = function () {
        self.myData.push(
            {
                textbox: ""
            });
    };

 this.checkData = function (){  
   //Here I want to get whats entered in all the textboxes

 }
```

Comment: What do you need the element name for? Don't you submit the form data via Ajax anyway?

Comment: Yes I have 2 buttons. With the above button I am just doing some validations on the input. With the other button I am doing an actual submit

Comment: The question was "Don't you submit the form data via Ajax anyway?".

Comment: Yes I am submitting the form data via Ajax. On form submission I can get the values in my model fine. But I want these textbox value on client side.

Comment: In the first line of your sample you set `this.add` to an observableArray, one line later you set set `this.add` to a function. Make up you mind what `this.add` should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's exceedingly likely that your entire approach is wrong.

- Your HTML input elements don't need names.
- Your viewmodel methods do not need to know anything about the HTML elements that display their values.
- You do not need to bind your event handlers with special parameters.

The view (the HTML page) is used as a tool for modifying the viewmodel. All data you need for verification is in the viewmodel, given that you have made everything that the user can change an `observable`.

```js
function Test() {
  var self = this;
    
  self.users  = ko.observableArray([
    { name: ko.observable("John Doe") },
    { name: ko.observable("Jane Doe") }
  ]);
  
  self.verify = function () {
    var usernames = self.users().map(function (u) { return ko.unwrap(u.name) });
    
    alert('You have entered these users\n\n' + usernames.join('\n'));
  };
}

var vm = new Test();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="foreach: users">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: name" /><br>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind='click: verify'>Check Data</button>
```

Comment: I have updated my code. You can check what I am looking for.

Comment: Your data (`textbox`) is not observable. Anything the user can change must be an observable. My code shows exactly what you need to do.